Does Entra ID Service Principal sign in logs include subject claims for Federated Credentials?
I'm trying to find some logs related to Federated Identity Credentials usage. I'm looking for subject claims in the logs but am not finding it.
AADServicePrincipalSignInLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(4h)
| where strlen(FederatedCredentialId) > 0
| where ServicePrincipalName == "spn-my-application"

This does not show any information about the Federated Credentials. Is there any other way I can get this info? Or is it even possible to get this info from Entra logs?

The Entra ID Service Principal sign-in logs do not include subject claims for Federated Credentials
